# Get Team users in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Is there a way to list out all the members of my team in bitbucket. Any api call?

Could not find anything here: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/teams

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's right on that very page: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/teams/%7Busername%7D/members

`$ curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/teams/atlassian/members`